# AS3 Works but I get a ReferenceError: Error #1069 Property startDrag not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, draggable, referenceerror

I am trying to make a simple project when you click a button a draggable MovieClip is added to the stag and when you click it releases the MovieClip to the X/Y where you clicked, you can then pickup the MovieClip and drag it into a bin (MovieClip) where it destroys itself. The code is working great I can make multiple Movieclips with the button and they are all destroyed when I drag them in the bin however I don't like having "Error Codes".

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var rubbish:my_mc = new my_mc();
btntest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeRubbish);

function makeRubbish (event:MouseEvent):void {


addChild(rubbish);

rubbish.x = mouseX - 10;
rubbish.y = mouseY - 10;
rubbish.width = 50;
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
rubbish.buttonMode = true;
}

function stopDragging (event:MouseEvent):void {
    rubbish.stopDrag()
    event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startDragging);
    rubbish.buttonMode = true;
            if (event.target.hitTestObject(bin))
            {
                trace("hit");
                 event.target.name = "rubbish"; 
    removeChild(getChildByName("rubbish"));


            }
}
function startDragging (event:MouseEvent):void {
event.target.startDrag();
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopDragging);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some Pointers**:

- The `target` property of an `Event` is not always what it seems. It actually refers to the current phase in the event bubbling process. Try using the `currentTarget` property.
- I would also recommend tying the `stopDragging` method to the stage, as sometimes your mouse won't be over the drag as you're clicking.
- I would use the `MOUSE_UP` event as opposed to a `CLICK` for standard dragging behaviour.
- When dragging, keep a global reference to the drag in order to call the `stopDrag` method on the correct object.

**Try This**:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var rubbish:my_mc = new my_mc();
var dragging:my_mc;

btntest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeRubbish);

function makeRubbish (event:MouseEvent):void {

  addChild(rubbish);

  rubbish.x = mouseX - 10;
  rubbish.y = mouseY - 10;
  rubbish.width = 50;
  rubbish.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
  rubbish.buttonMode = true;

}

function stopDragging (event:MouseEvent):void {

  this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

  if(dragging !== null){

    dragging.stopDrag();

    if (event.currentTarget.hitTestObject(bin)){

      removeChild(dragging);

    }

    dragging = null;

  }
}

function startDragging (event:MouseEvent):void {

  dragging = event.currentTarget as my_mc;

  dragging.startDrag();

  this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

}
```

Comment: hmm I'm still getting the error but now the whole stage moves when I drag and it doesn't like to let go of the rubbish

Comment: line 41 error 1118 implict coercion of value with a static type to a possible unrelated type my_mc

Comment: @ChelsieRaeMcNulty Try now. Note the change is `dragging = event.currentTarget as my_mc;`

Comment: No errors anymore however the rubbish is deleted after you drag and let go anywhere on the stage, it doesn't have to hit the bin like it should? its like collision is always on?

Comment: seems to work perfect with no errors if I change dragging = event.currentTarget as my_mc; to event.taget